# Does the Google App Engine DataStore need to be load tested?

Tags: google-app-engine, load-testing, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Datastore, and would like to know, is it necessary to load test App Engine Datastore? If so, how? The App Engine scales automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be load-testing Google App Engine / Datastore, let Google engineers do their job. You should focus solely on your application performance.

Any external domains need to be [excluded](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1903905-excluding-domains-from-the-load-test) from the load test as:

- It isn't something you can control
- Your IP address(es) may be banned